# Table Storage Index

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm designing table storage partition and row key for fast querying. Can we confirm whether the index has hit or not ? I would like to check the index performance.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain what you mean by the following - `Can we confirm whether the index has hit or not`? Thanks!

Comment: I consider that the query will execute by full scanning if the index is not designed accordingly. I want to confirm that the query executes using index (or not execute by full scanning).

Comment: AFAIK, Azure Tables does not provide any information on index usage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. So we can't check index usage, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Table creates index upon Partition Key + Row Key, which means:

- Querying with both Partition Key and Row Key specified is the most efficient;
- Querying with Partition Key only specified will cause whole Partition Scan;
- Querying with Row Key only specified will cause whole Table Scan (which is the worse case).

I'd suggest you to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide before proceeding designing.

Comment: I disagree with the answer. Azure Tables does have indexing (automatic on PartitionKey and RowKey). Its just that it does not have user defined indexing i.e. one can't define indexes on any other attributes.

Comment: I didn't mean Azure Storage Table doesn't have indexing inside. What I meant is that Azure Table doesn't provide a feature to add index for a column. Sorry for the confusion, let me update me answer anyway.